# Table and image alignment

Tags: tables, graphics, tabu

I am trying to have an image on the left and a table description on the right. Currently, this is what I have:

```
\taburulecolor |grey!50|{steelblue} \arrayrulewidth=1pt
\begin{tabu}{XX[3]}
    \toprule
    \parbox[c]{1em}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/portrait.png}} &
        \begin{tabu}{XX[2]}
            Name            & \em Logan\\
            Also known as   & Nine Fingers\\
            \midrule
            Gender          & \\
            Height          & \\
            Weight          & \\
            \midrule
            Nature          & \\
            Demeanour       & \\
            Idiosyncrasies  & \\
            \midrule
            Phobia          & \\
            Fears           & \\
            Hopes           & \\
            \midrule
        \end{tabu} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabu}
```

Which renders as such.

[image: images of that the code generated]

*How do I align the image with the inner table?*

Answer (score 5):

with

```
\parbox[c]{1em}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/portrait.png}}
```

you have put the reference point of the image in its vertical centre, which then aligns with the top row of the table, instead use

```
\parbox[t]{1em}{\vspace{0pt}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/portrait.png}}
```

so the reference point is at the top of the image box. You may want to adjust the 0pt by eye to some other value to get the right visual effect.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I'll wait for 24 hours before accepting this answer unless someone else comes with a mind-blowing one.